# Is there a way to resize a buffer in C++

Tags: c++, memory, allocator

I'm a noob to memory management so please forgive me. Say I have the following code:

```
std::allocator<T> alloc;

T* buffer = alloc.allocate(42);
```

Is there a good way to "add space" to this buffer, instead of creating a new buffer, allocating more space, copying the old buffer to the new buffer, and then replacing the old buffer?

Comment: Can't you use a std::vector instead of manual memory management?

Comment: Such thing cannot be done. Even with [realloc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) you may (and likely will) copy data rather sooner than later. However you may want to consider a linked list of buffers. Or don't worry about it and copy it, for example that's how std::vector works (and it does it for you).

Comment: @drescherjm I am creating my own std::vector implementation. In my reserve function a new buffer gets created, allocated with more space, and then replaces the old buffer.

Comment: You seem to have an XY-problem. What is the underlying problem you're trying to solve this way?

Comment: @beangod so you must already know that this is how std::vector works internally. What seems to be the problem exactly?

Comment: If you are creating your own `std::vector` implementation, can you explain why you would not do what `std::vector` does in this situation?

Comment: @beangod - The standard "trick" is for user code to call reserve() while the vector is still empty.

Comment: @Beangod "I am creating my own std::vector implementation" - Why on earth would you do that???

Comment: There's nothing wrong with creating one's own reimplementation of vector, as a learning excersize. However, to successfully do that one needs to understand how the existing vector works and why, precisely. It is key to actually and fully understand what one is trying to reimplement.

Comment: ***Is there a good way to "add space" to this buffer, instead of creating a new buffer, allocating more space, copying the old buffer to the new buffer, and then replacing the old buffer?*** Not really if you require a single contiguous allocation. However you may want to use the technique that a vector does. What I mean is have a  size and a capacity concept where the capacity is allocated larger than the size on purpose to reduce the number of allocation and copy operations.

Comment: Usually not. Consider: what if there was already something else allocated right after the end of your existing buffer? (There could be. How would the allocator know not to put things there?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No.

In general you can't use `realloc`. The problem is that resizing the buffer may or may not mean allocating a new, larger buffer somewhere else and then it depends on `T` what you have to do. `T` may be trivially copyable, in which case `realloc` would work. But it's unlikely for `realloc` to actually just grow the buffer. That only happens when you accidentally have reusable memory after the old buffer. Basically never happens.

If `T` is not trivially copyable then calling `realloc` is UB when it needs to allocate a new buffer somewhere else. `T` might have a copy constructor that needs to be called on every object when it is copied. `realloc` won't do that. You have to allocate a new buffer and copy all the objects from the old buffer to the new buffer. No big loss since the chance that realloc will actually be able to just grow the buffer is miniscule.

Better if `T` has a move constructor because that's faster than copying. But then you have to consider what happens when the constructor throws an exception. Maybe somewhere in the middle when you have moved half your objects. So you have to move everything back to the old buffer before throwing the exception again. What if that causes another exception?

Basically you don't want to move unless the move constructor is noexcept. Copying is the safer fallback.

All of those things and probably a bunch more have been considered in `std::vector`, which is why you should just use that.